# Difference between Looper.prepareMainLooper() and Looper.prepare()?

Tags: android, android-looper

What is the difference between Looper.prepareMainLooper() and Looper.prepare()?

Answer (score 1):

The difference betwenn is `Looper.prepareMainLooper()` and `Looper.prepare()` is  that :

`Looper.prepareMainLooper()` prepares looper in `main thread`.

And `Looper.prepare()` prepares Looper in `current thread`.

[Read more here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper)